# Is it necessary to separate SCCM, SUP, and WSUS roles

Tags: wsus, sccm

I ran a test setup with at my company where I deployed SCCM to one of our VMs, but I never used our WSUS server, nor did we have a SUP server.

Just how crucial is it that these three remain separate? In my test setup, I had our DP on the Primary Site server as well, should I keep these things on separate VMs? We have roughly a 100 users and plan on using OS deployments, Software deployments, asset monitoring, Windows Updates, and Software Updates.

I ask because I'm now deploying SCCM 2019, and want to know if I should separate these server roles or consolidate them to their own VMs.

Comment: Let me know if this needs more info or clarification, I'm in the middle of helping 3 users while trying to get this all nailed down lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a <100.000 client scenario you really don't need to worry.

WSUS and a Primary Site run perfectly together on one host. The SUP (Softer Update Point) is just a SCCM role.

You basically can choose between these two layouts:

- One VM

  - With SCCM Primary Site
  - With SUP role
  - With WSUS
- Two VMs

  - **VM one with:**
  - SCCM Primary Site
  - **VM two with:**
  - SCCM Site Server role
  - SCCM SUP role
  - WSUS role

If you want to learn more head over to MS Technet, this topic is actually very well described and documented: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/system-center-2012-R2/hh846235(v=technet.10)

Another very good resource is: https://www.prajwaldesai.com/sccm/

Comment: https://www.prajwaldesai.com/sccm/

This site is the truth, I used it to set up SCCM already, but he didn't really talk much about whether or not they needed to be on separate servers. I supposed the real reason to split them is the same reason you split every other server role you may have: work on one won't impact the status of the other. For instance, you have to restart SCCM/WSUS, and it won't bring down WSUS/SCCM respectively.